# How to get column names from PDO's fetchAll result?

Tags: php, pdo

I create a code to display from a table

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table"; 
$stmt = $dbcon->prepare($sql); 
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

to display the result, I use the following ode:

```
<?php foreach($result as $readrow){ ?>
<div class="table-row">
<td><?php echo $readrow['id'];?></td>
<td><?php echo $readrow['area'];?></td>
<td><?php echo $readrow['color'];?></td>
<?php } ?>
```

Is there any way, the table can be displayed with the header?

Comment: What do you mean by header? What would be the header name, the selected table?

Comment: Yes, header for selected table. The code i show is header for 'Country' table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many duplicated questions but all answers are beyond any reason, offering complicated solutions involving running extra queries etc.

While the solution is right here: when using `fetchAll()`, you already have all the column headers in the `$result` variable

```
$headerNames = $result ? array_keys($result[0]) : [];
```

now you can foreach over `$coulmnNames` to get the table header and the foreach over $result to display the results.

```
<table class='table'>
  <tr>
  <?php foreach($coulmnNames as $name): ?>
    <th><?= $name ?></th>
  <?php endforeach ?>
  </tr>
  <?php foreach($result as $row){ ?>
    <tr class="table-row">
      <?php foreach($result as $value){ ?>
        <td><?= $value ?></td>
    </tr>
  <?php endforeach ?>
</table>
```